# Setear un nuevo metodo para Elementos del DOM

Tags: javascript

Buenas como lo indica el titulo, alguna forma de setear un metodo a los elementos del dom?

Mi duda es como puedo setear metodos de la forma que estan seteados .textContent .length es decir accesibles como metodos para sus tipos de elementos correspondientes.

por que lo pregunto? bueno quiero crear un metodo que este disponible para los 'Element object ' del dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esto necesitas modificar el prototipo del elemento. Si es un botón: `HTMLButtonElement` si es un elemento canvas: `HTMLCanvasElement`... etc

```js
// agrega un nuevo método a los elementos button
HTMLButtonElement.prototype.unMetodo = function(){
  console.log("es un boton")
}


document.querySelector("button").unMetodo()
```

```html
<button>Un boton</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tal como lo planteas, te diría que añadir métodos a un elemento del DOM es una mala práctica en sí, te puede dar lugar a comportamientos inconsistentes y aleatorios.

Mi recomendación es que uses un customElement en su lugar que implemente el método que quieras añadir, un ejemplo sería el que te pongo a continuación:

```js
class MyCustomButton extends HTMLButtonElement {
  
  static get is() {return 'my-custom-button'}
  
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  
  myCustomMethod(myVar) {
    console.log(myVar);
  }
}

customElements.define(MyCustomButton.is, MyCustomButton, {extends: 'button'})

document.querySelector('button[is="my-custom-button"]').myCustomMethod('jamon');
```

```html
<button is="my-custom-button">
Hola
</button>
```

Con esto podrías hacer lo que pides.